# Angular ng-repeat once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an angular ng-repeat function. it repeats all the items in my list perfectly, but i need the items to only show one time.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item item-stable" ng-repeat="departure in flightSource" padding="false" ng-click="custom=!custom">
        <div class="center">
            Terminal {{departure.airportResources.departureTerminal}}
            <div ng-hide="custom">hello</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JSON**:
As you can see I get two "TERMINAL 4" 's
I only want one to show if it has been repeated already.

```
airportResources:
    ObjectarrivalGate: "A9"
    departureGate: "14"
    departureTerminal: "1"

airportResources:
    ObjectarrivalGate: "B1"
    baggage: "5"
    departureGate: "44B"
    departureTerminal: "4"

airportResources:
    ObjectdepartureGate: "44F"
    departureTerminal: "4"

etc...
```

Comment: You need a custom filter or an intermediate list that you would create from your departure list in your controller.

Comment: So you do not want to show multiple airportResources with the same departureTerminal?

Comment: In your Angular JS controller use a for loop to loop through the JSON and push data into a local array and put the "push" command within an if statement which checks whether an element with the same name already exists within your local array. For example "terminal = 4" If the all the data in the local array does not contain a "terminal = 4" then push otherwise skip that item and go to the next one. once that is done the use your local array to do ng-repeat on the front end. Hope this helps.  But why don't you want to show the same terminal, the terminal is same but the flight is different.

Comment: @linstantnoodles yes thats what im trying to do but only shoe the departure terminal once in the view. So it would show "Terminal 1, Terminal 2, Terminal 3". Not "Terminal 1. Terminal 2, Terminal 2, Terminal 3".

Comment: @user2190986 alright I will try that solution. And say the user chooses Terminal 2, an array of Gates will show with all items that contain Terminal 2

Comment: Can you use the AngularJS unique filter like such : `expression | unique:'property'`? In your example can you attempt `departure in flightSource | unique: 'departureTerminal`

Comment: Just use a custom filter just as @sbarnard said.

Comment: @sbarnard Thanks! Worked Perfectly!!

Comment: You are very welcome! :) Always happy to share some knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom filter like such:

```
<div ng-repeat="d in Resources | unique: 'airportResources.departureTerminal'">
    <div class="center">
        Terminal {{d.airportResources.departureTerminal}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And as an added bonus you don't have to write the custom filter yourself. It is part of a companion library called Angular-UI. I have implemented the solution for you at the following plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JVdgO8NYTnZAWAgQJbXa?p=preview